# Binding multiple callbacks for promises returns resolve value of first promise, not second

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following code as part of some coding practice I am doing:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('hello world');
    }, 2000);
});

var promiseTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('hello again!');
    }, 2000);
});

promise.then(promiseTwo).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

When the data is logged, it reads `hello world` and not `hello again!`. Why is that? My thinking was that the line `promise.then(promiseTwo).then((data) => { console.log(data) })`
would resolve the first promise, then pass the second promise in as a callback which would resolve to `hello again!`. Why does the resolve in `promiseTwo` never get return from the `.then` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not returning `promiseTwo` in `then`, you're simply calling it, try:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('hello world');
    }, 2000);
});

var promiseTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('hello again!');
    }, 2000);
});

promise.then(() => promiseTwo).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: So then in my example, I'm calling it to execute the code but just not returning it?